# AngularJS repeat filter strings ending with the letter G

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an AngularJS app, and need to display object properties that end with a G on one line, and ones without the G on another:

```
<div class="col"><strong>Grass</strong>
  <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in player.ranking" ng- 
  filter="value.endsWith('G') = true">
  <span class="text-success">{{key.replace('Pool', '')}} {{value}}<span ng- 
  if="!$last">, &nbsp;</span></span></span>
</div>
<div class="col"><strong>Beach:</strong>
  <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in player.ranking" ng- 
  filter="!value.endsWith('G')">
  <span class="text-warning">{{key.replace('Pool', '')}} {{value}}<span ng- 
  if="!$last">,&nbsp; </span></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

What I have isn't working.  Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure where you got the `ng-filter` attribute from. However, this is not a valid filter for `ng-repeat` in **AngularJS**.

The correct format is:

```
item in items | filter:searchText
```

In your HTML it looks something like:

```
 <ul ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query ">
      <li>{{item.name}}</li>
    </ul>
```

So the quickest solution to your problem is to use a filter function

**html**

```
 <ul ng-repeat="item in items |
      filter: filterFunction ">
      <li>{{friend.name}} ({{friend.age}})</li>
    </ul>
```

**JS**

```
  $scope.filterFunction = function(value) {
      return value.endsWith('G');
    };
```

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up realizing what I was doing wrong.  ng-filter was ng-if before i posted, as I was getting desperate and willing to try anything at the time.  I used ng-if="key.includes('G')"    to display grass rankings, and ng-if="!key.includes('G')" to display beach rankings and it worked!